# JSTL in custom tag not parsed

Tags: jsp, jstl

I've implemented a custom tag that print some information about the logged user using JSTL core and format libary. Everything is working but the `getJspContext().getOut().println("<fmt:message key='search'/>");` is not parsed in the JSP.

In the page, the `<fmt:message` is not interpreted.

This is my code:

navbar.tld

```
<tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
<jsp-version>2.0</jsp-version>
<short-name>testing</short-name>
<uri>/WEB-INF/tld/navbar.tld</uri>
<description>This is a demonstration tag library</description>

<tag>
    <name>userInformation</name>
    <tag-class>tag.NavbarTagHandler</tag-class>
    <body-content>scriptless</body-content>
    <description>This tag is for displaying headers of the navbar</description>

</tag>
```

NavbarTagHandler

```
public class NavbarTagHandler extends SimpleTagSupport {

@Override
public void doTag() throws JspException {
    User user = null;
    user = (User) getJspContext().getAttribute("authenticatedUser", PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE);

    JspWriter out = getJspContext().getOut();

    try {
        if (user == null) {
            //not logged
            out.println("Not logged <fmt:message key='message1'/>");
            out.flush();
        } else {
            //logged
            out.println("Logged <fmt:message key='message2'/>");
            out.flush();
        }
    } catch (IOException es) {
        es.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

How can make it parsable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The used custom taglib is from `JSP spec 1.0` and it does not allow nested tag interpretation.
In order to achieve this you need to use `JSP spec 2.0` taglib specification which allows us to implement a JSP as a taglib.

Therefore,it allows using multiple tags within one taglib implementation.

1. Define the taglib content in a `.tag` file,along with the external taglibs
2. Refer the taglib in the general usable format

---

#### Elaboration

In order to create an use a custome tag,we need to follow couple of steps:

1. Create a tag file,defining the attributes used by it and any variables which will be used by the tag

   a. The attributes need to have a name,their type and and required field with a boolean value

   b. The variables will be defined with a name along with a certain scope-

   NESTED(Available in tag body),

   AT_BEGIN(Within tag till end of scope) and

   AT_END(From end of tag till end of scope)

   ```
       <%@ attribute name="name" required="true" type="java.lang.String" description="Name of User"  %>
       <%@ attribute name="role" required="true" type="java.lang.String" description="Role of User" %>
       <%@ variable name-given="passBack" scope="AT_BEGIN"%>
       <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

       <h1>${name}</h1>
       <h2>${role}</h2>

       <%String backToCaller="Back to caller";%>
       <c:set var="passBack" value="Pass back successful"/>
   ```
2. Define the entry to import tag,where tagdir will be directory containing tag file with .tag extension

   ```
   <%@ taglib prefix="tags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
   ```
3. Finally use the tag,passing the required attributes,as per tag definition.
   Here `customTag` is the name of the tag file,along with prefix as defined

   ```
   <tags:customTag name="Hello Tag!!" role="I am the boss here"/>
   ```
4. The variable set from tag can be retrieved in the caller jsp using expression language

   Hello ${passBack}